# Growing UIWebView causing "Received memory warning." and eventually crashes app with "Terminated due to Memory Error"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiwebview

So I have an UIWebView inside an UINavigationController which is inside a UITabBarController, where the UIWebView basically make the whole view.

Inside the UIWebView I'm displaying content from a web-server which grows in height as you scroll down and reach the bottom. After a while, I start getting memory warnings and after some more scrolling, eventually, the whole app crashes with an error message saying `Terminated due to Memory Error`.

However, I've carefully monitored the memory usage of the app and can't find anything indicating that the app fills the memory or anything like this.

I've also logged the content size of the web views scroll view when I receive the warnings and the hight varies from 30 000 up to 60 000 until I get the first warning. I've also tried running the HTML content without any image elements, didn't make any noticeable difference.

So, what am I missing?
Is the memory being filled somehow, causing the app to crash?

Any suggestions on debug tools/methods I could try?

All tips are most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Try using paginated web page and you can cache data for pages using NSURLProtocol.

It would load pages and cache onto disk so navigation backward would be from cached and only 1 page would be in memory which is being viewed.

That is best you can do with UIWebView OR you may go for MKWebView it can allow you additional features.